# How to scrape Raphaël SVG in Python using BS4, Scrapy or something similar?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

[Here's the site](http://www.sanzarrugby.com/therugbychampionship/match-centre/?season=2018&competition=214&match=2891#matchstatstab) I want to scrape. I want to scrape the numbers in the action area (5.3% , 12.8% etc.) . It is an svg made using Raphaël. Currently I have no clue what so ever to scrape it because it's all just SVGAnimatedString. Any solutions please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem is that this website creates its content using Javascript. It is probably possible to determine the call it makes to get the data you need and request that directly, or an alternative approach would be for you to use `selenium` to automate a browser. This would then wait for the webpage to fully render and you can then extract the complete HTML from that.

You could then use `beautifulsoup` to help with parsing the HTML that is returned. For example:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.sanzarrugby.com/therugbychampionship/match-centre/?season=2018&competition=214&match=2891#matchstatstab"

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, "html.parser")
data = [v.text for v in soup.svg.find_all('tspan')]

print data
```

Giving you `data` holding a list of entries as follows:

```
[u'The Rugby Championship', u'Australia v. South Africa', u'Possession', u'5.3%', u'12.8%', u'29.4%', u'10.2%', u'3.2%', u'11.8%', u'15.0%', u'12.3%', u'58%', u'42%']
```

You will need to investigate how to install these packages.

Comment: First of all thank you very much for your answer. I do have a one question though. Will this work with a linux VPS machine? Because it just opens up Firefox on my computer, which is logical I guess, but won't that create an error?

Comment: Figured it out, needed to install pyvirtualdisplay and seems to do it. Thank you!